# spin with threads

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm having problems with spin and multiples subscriptions. I want to subscribe to two topic and going on with my program.
Something like:

```
X_callback(){something};
Y_callback(){something};


int main(){
thread(subscribe to topic X with callback X_callback)
thread(subscribe to topic Y_callback)
more things to do...
}
```

I don't know what to do with spin() if I've threads. I've used Multithread spin but doesn't work. Doing something like:

```
MultiThreadSping s(4);

X_callback(){s.spin()};
Y_callback(){s.spin()};

int main(){
some code
}
```

EDIT. This was my first idea:

```
void alivesCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg){
    //control new connection
}

void temperatureCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr &msg){
    temperature = msg->data;
}


void subscriptionAliveTopic(){
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("alive", 1000, alivesCallback);
    ros::spin();
}


void subscriptionTemperatureTopic(){
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("temperature", 1000, temperatureCallback);
    ros::spin();
}


int main(){
    
    boos::thread t1(boost::bind(subscriptionAliveTopic));
    boos::thread t2(boost::bind(subscriptionTemperatureTopic));

    //more things to do
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66708/spin-with-threads/) by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-07-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-07-05**:
Can you clarify your question a bit?  Do you just want to subscribe to two topics? Is there a reason that you need threads, other than for the subscriptions?

**Comment by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on 2013-07-05**:
Each thread is the subscription and the spin. I'm using threads beacuse I'm trying not to block the main program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to do what you're looking for is to call `spinOnce` in a loop.  This is non-blocking, and allows you to do other operations in "parallel" with the callback processing.  Note that this is not truly parallel, since this is a single-threaded model, but many applications are fine without truly multi-threaded operations.

See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) for more discussion of various spinning methods.

Try something like this:

```
my_callback(){something};

int main(){
  sub = node.subscribe("topic", &my_callback);

  ros::Rate r(10); // 10 hz
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    do_callback_independent_processing();

    if (new_callback_data)
      do_callback_dependent_processing();

    ros::spinOnce();
    r.sleep();
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
If you don't like the idea of calling `spinOnce` in a loop, then probably the next-best choice is to use `ASyncSpinner`.  Trying to use multiple threads and multiple calls to `ros::spin()` is messy, and probably won't work.  `ros::spin` explicitly states that it is designed for single-threaded nodes only.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The subscriptions don't block the control flow in `main()`, so you don't need to put them in threads.  All that they do is to register the callback with the callback manager (which will not fire then until you run `spin()`).  So, the following should work

```
int main() {
  // These will not block.
  subscribe to topic X with callback X_callback
  subscribe to topic Y with callback Y_callback

  [other stuff]

  spin();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on 2013-07-05**:
But below spin() I need to do more things. So if I put sping() and then some code, spin() would block it.

**Comment by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on 2013-07-05**:
Below spin() I need to use the data obtained in the callbacks.

**Comment by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on 2013-07-05**:
Is it possible to make the subscription to the two topics, then run a thread with spin() and continuing with the main execution?

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-07-05**:
ROS is inherently callback-driven, making what you describe a bit awkward.  Can you put the code that needs to use the data from the callbacks in the callbacks themselves, or have it called from there?  I might help to know what sort of things you want to do after the spin.

**Comment by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on 2013-07-05**:
Edited my first comment.